# Why is unix_timestamp parsing this incorrectly by 12 hours off?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, unix-timestamp

The following appears to be incorrect (`spark.sql`):

```sql
select unix_timestamp("2017-07-03T12:03:56", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
-- 1499040236
```

Compared to:

```sql
select unix_timestamp("2017-07-03T00:18:31", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
-- 1499041111
```

Clearly the first comes after the second. And the second appears to be correct:

```r
# ** R Code **
# establish constants
one_day = 60 * 60 * 24
one_year = 365 * one_day
one_year_leap = 366 * one_day
one_quad = 3 * one_year + one_year_leap

# to 2014-01-01
11 * one_quad +
  # to 2017-01-01
  2 * one_year + one_year_leap + 
  # to 2017-07-01
  (31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30) * one_day + 
  # to 2017-07-03 00:18:31
  2 * one_day + 18 * 60 + 31
# [1] 1499041111
```

A similar calculation shows the first should be `1499083436` (confirmed by `as.integer(as.POSIXct('2017-07-03 12:03:56', tz = 'UTC'))` in R), and that `1499040236` should correspond to `2017-07-03 00:03:56`.

So what's happening here? It certainly looks like a bug. Two last sanity checks -- `select unix_timestamp("2017-07-03T00:03:56", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")` correctly returns `1499040236`; and replacing the `T` in the middle with a space  has no effect on the incorrect parse.

---

Since it appears to be fixed in development, I'll note that this is on `2.1.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a format mistake:

- Your data is in 0-23 hour format (denoted in [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) as `HH`).
- You use `hh` format which corresponds to 1-24 hour format.

In fact, in the latest Spark version (2.3.0 RC1) it wouldn't parse at all:

```scala
spark.version
```

```
String = 2.3.0
```

```scala
spark.sql("""
  select unix_timestamp("2017-07-03T00:18:31", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")""").show
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(2017-07-03T00:18:31, yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)|
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      null|
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: even more subtle -- that one actually _shouldn't_ return `null`

Comment: Yeah, and there is of course timestamp semantics, which can result in different timezones on different nodes :)

Comment: Oh my, the `2.1.1` behavior is quite pernicious -- `select unix_timestamp("2017-07-03T13:18:31", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")` returns `13` as the hour -- it's only _exactly_ `12` which is ambiguous and thrown out (I found some older code that made the same mistake and was wondering how I could have missed something so obvious)