# Incorrect difference in dates with different formats

Tags: r

I have dates that look like this:

> ```
> [474] "26-08-18" "1-09-18" "1-09-18"  "1-09-18"  "1-09-18"  "2-09-18"
> ```

and I would like to subtract another date, but I am finding the following problem:

```
> (fdate <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2018-09-12"
> as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%Y") - fdate
Time difference of -730467 days
```

I have solved the problem by using the `lubridate` package as follows:

```
> lubridate::dmy("30-09-18") - as.Date(Sys.Date())
Time difference of 18 days
```

However I was surprised that using `as.Date` (and specifying the`format`) does not work. Why is that ? [Or rather, what am I doing wrong in base R ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To our eyes, we immediately see (given that we're writing this in 2018) that `30-09-18` means September 30, 2018 CE; the computer (i.e. R), however, needs some help (as encapsulated in the `format` string).

You've told it the last part of your input is `%Y`-formatted; therefore it interpreted per instructions in `?strptime`:

> Year **with century**. [...]

So, R sees `30-09-18` and thinks "September 30, 18 CE". Of course that was a long time ago:

```
as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%Y") - as.Date('2018-09-12')
# Time difference of -730467 days
```

It should be about 2000 years ago, right?

```
730467/365.25 # rudimentary accounting for leap years/centuries
# [1] 1999.91
```

To remedy the issue, a handy  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  on `?strptime` for `year` can help identify the correct option, `%y`:

> Year without century (`00–99`). On input, values `00` to `68` are prefixed by `20` and `69` to `99` by `19` – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

And then the expected result:

```
as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%y") - as.Date('2018-09-12')
# Time difference of 18 days
```

Lesson being, always double/triple-check the `?strptime` manual when encountering unexpected behavior... [Speaking from experience!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357091/why-is-unix-timestamp-parsing-this-incorrectly-by-12-hours-off)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much just formalising the above comments:

**Issue:**

1. **as.Date conversion**

`as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%Y")`

*Outputs:*
`[1] "0018-09-30"`

By specifying the "%Y" it's expecting a yyyy input so in your case assumes 0018

```
as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%y")
```

*Outputs* : `[1] "2018-09-30"`

Therefore

```
as.Date("30-09-18", format="%d-%m-%y") - Sys.Date()
```

Outputs: `Time difference of 18 days`